# Selection changed event in CListView based SDI application

Tags: c++, mfc

I am developing MFC SDI application. My view is derived from `CListView` class. I would like to handle the selection changed event for the list control. I'm not able to add `WM_NOTIFY` message handler as I don't know how to get the ID of the created listview. Please help me.

Comment: Have you seen LVN_ITEMCHANGED message ? Handle this message, and you will know when you have changed the selection of the list ...

Comment: @flaviu2: That doesn't address the question at all. The OP doesn't know, which control ID to use for the [`ON_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/749htf6k.aspx) macro.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add the following to your message map:

`ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, &OnItemChanged)`

And here is your event handler:

```
void CMyListView::OnItemChanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{ 
    NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR; 

    // Did the item state change?
    if (pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
    {
        // Did the item selection change?
        const bool oldSelState = (pNMListView->uOldState & LVIS_SELECTED) != 0x0;
        const bool newSelState = (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED) != 0x0;
        const bool selStateChanged = oldSelState != newSelState;
        if(selStateChanged)
        {
            // TODO: handle selection change; use newSelState where appropriate
        }
    }
    *pResult = 0; 
}
```

Comment: For details on message reflection see [TN062: Message Reflection for Windows Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd.aspx).